# How to start windows phone 8 app development?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I am new to mobile application development...I would like to develop windows phone 8 apps.
Can you please answer my following questions

1. What are the softwares needed to develop WP8 apps?
2. What are the hardware requirements?
3. I heard that SDK for WP* is not available yet, is that true?When it will be available?

Thank you and Regards
Yashavantha G M

Comment: Wait for the official announcement from Microsoft on the availability of the tools :)

Comment: go here  https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/oem?contentName=docs%2FGetting_Started%2FPreparing_for_Windows_Phone_development#sdk